# Facebook read_mailbox permission in Android App

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

Is it possible to read user inbox through the Facebook SDK for android? Because, i have set the extended permission `read_mailbox`, yet I'm getting the error message:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 298, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#298) Requires extended permission: read_mailbox}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***read_mailbox*** is deprecated as of v2.4 & will no longer be supported from 6th Oct, 2015. Please read below links:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#reference-read_mailbox
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3